# Programatically hiding and showing individual tabs in React Native Router Flux Tabbar

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have a tabbar in my app using React Native Router Flux. There are a couple use cases where hiding or showing specific tabs based on the current user would be very helpful. The main ones I have run into are:

- AB testing new tabs to specific users
- Showing a special admin tab to certain users with certain privileges

The react-native-router-flux library does not support any options to do this from what I can see. How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default tabbar component in react-native-router-flux is just the component from the `react-navigation-tabs` library. You can import this component directly into your code, customize as needed, and then pass it to `react-native-router-flux` through the `tabBarComponent` prop ([documented here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#tabs-tabs-or-scene-tabs)).

I created a new component, which you should be able to copy directly and just change the logic for actually hiding the tabs based on your state:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const HiddenView = () => <View style={{ display: 'none' }} />
const TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper = ({
  onPress,
  onLongPress,
  testID,
  accessibilityLabel,
  ...props
}) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={onPress}
    onLongPress={onLongPress}
    testID={testID}
    hitSlop={{
      left: 15,
      right: 15,
      top: 5,
      bottom: 5,
    }}
    accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
  >
    <View {...props} />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
)
const TabBarComponent = props => (
  <BottomTabBar
    {...props}
    getButtonComponent={({ route }) => {
      if (
        (route.key === 'newTab' && !props.showNewTab) ||
        (route.key === 'oldTab' && props.hideOldTab)
      ) {
        return HiddenView
      }
      return TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper
    }}
  />
)

export default connect(
  state => ({ /* state that you need */ }),
  {},
)(TabBarComponent)
```

And then simply imported and used that in my Tabs component:

```
<Tabs
  key="main"
  tabBarComponent={TabBarComponent} // the component defined above
  ...
```

**Detailed look at where these things are getting passed to**

Looking at [the line of the source](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/b37a24b780d75879512903b5cf7ef297f5b3721a/src/navigationStore.js#L833) of react-native-router-flux, it is using `createBottomTabNavigator` from the `react-navigation` library, and passing no component if you do not pass a custom tabBarComponent. The `createBottomTabNavigator` method in `react-navigation` comes [from this line of the library](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/4502061a1081704b34db82aa742a4ba8f7f04e4a/src/react-navigation.js#L113), and is actually defined in `react-navigation-tabs`. Now, we can [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/blob/master/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js#L48) see in `react-navigation-tabs` that if no tabBarComponent has been passed, it simply uses BottomTabBar, also defined in `react-navigation-tabs`. This `BottomTabBar`, in turn, [takes a custom tab button renderer through props](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/blob/master/src/views/BottomTabBar.js#L232), called `getButtonComponent`.

Comment: Actually the `return TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper;` has the same effect to `return null;` and you can remove the `TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper` redefine.