# Is there any way to hide parent tabbar in react native router flux?

Tags: react-native, tabbar, react-native-router-flux

I have parent tabbar and inside one of the tabs I have another tabbar. When I navigate inside of the child tabbar scene, both of the tabbars are visible. I want only child tabbar to be available. Below code is not working.('Tab' here is parent tabbar key)

`Actions.refresh({key:'Tab',   hideTabBar: true})`

How do I access Parent Tabbar, or how do I hide parent tabbar? I have followed below link and was able to hide parent tabbar but not perfectly:

[Programatically hiding and showing individual tabs in React Native Router Flux Tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872145/programatically-hiding-and-showing-individual-tabs-in-react-native-router-flux-t)

During that transition of hiding its still available on scene for 2 seconds. Any suggestion
will be helpful. Thank you.